# How to disable global(File-->Rename) menu in RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I am stuck with this issue since yesterday. I want to disable (or hide) the default eclipse rename menu item under file contextual menu.

I was able to hide the one under right click menu using activities like:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity id="rename.disable" name="Hidden activities">
       <enabledWhen>
         <not> <reference  definitionId="DataEnginePlugin.testProjectNatureExtension"/></not>
       </enabledWhen>
    </activity>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="rename.disable" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename"/>
    </extension>
```

But, i am not able to disable the global one under File menu (F2).

Any ideas please!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the pattern for the `activityPatternBinding` is 'contributing plugin id / item id'. Also the default pattern is a regular expression, you want an exact match here. So you want:

```xml
<activityPatternBinding 
  isEqualityPattern="true"
  activityId="rename.disable" 
  pattern="org.eclipse.ui/org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename"/>
```

Comment: Thank you greg for your prompt answer, however what u mentioned does not disable the global rename menu (File->Rename) or F2.